# Getting n-element combination from table of attributes values

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

My problem is create algorithm to receive n-element combination of attributes values that I later compare with records in file. I code in Java and table of values of attributes is represented as LinkedList< LinkedList< String [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwIQB.png)] > > (of course I could change this representation).
Example table could look like this:

[(Link) Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwIQB.png)

For combination of one element it's enough to code three nested for loops, but how to handle combination of n=elements? Combinations of the same attributes and the same attributes values are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `n` nested loops, you may use recursion.

However, a simpler way to deal with this may be just looping like this:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> L;
// Init L

// begin looping
int N = 1;
for(LinkedList<String> l in L)
    N *= l.length;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    int[] chooseWhich = new int[L.length];
    for(int j = 0; j < L.length; j++){
        chooseWhich[j] = i % L[j].length;
        i /= L[j].length;
    }
    // at this stage, you have the i-th column chosen to be chooseWhich[i]
    // do whatever you want just as you have nested n loops
}
```

By the way, I have just realized that LinkedList doesn't have length, but you many change to use array. Or you can maintain the length of the linked list somewhere by yourself.